# How to update a Redis key expiration on read/write?

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data, lettuce

I'm using Redis with Spring/Lettuce with a `org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository` to persist a session defined as a `@RedisHash` to Redis. I want to update the TTL on every access, read or write. I thought there might be some hook I could use as with JPA Entity Lifecycle Events, but I couldn't find any.

Are there any other options?

Comment: Using a pipeline and setting the new ttl on each read/write seams fine

Comment: Yeah, that would be good, but where do I insert the pipeline? Not in the repo code. Maybe in the entity? How?

Comment: I mean, just replace your reads/writes by a pipeline. If you have access to a redis instance you should be able to do a pipeline. Replace ```redis.get``` by ```redis.pipeline().get().ttl().exec()```, something like that

Comment: That's certainly possible, but it means creating my own Repository implementation, instead of using CrudRepository. I was wondering if there is another way.

Comment: Long story short you wants to store the Entity state in `Redis` ?

Comment: @JeevananthanS Yep.